# git - branching from local repo

Tags: git, git-branch

I am trying to set up a local repository (LOCAL_REPO) from some git branch (MASTER) which is to be used by a group of people.

MASTER------>LOCAL_REPO

To do this i did the following :

1. git clone /path to master
2. git checkout -b LOCAL_REPO MASTER

This creates a branch LOCAL_REPO for me at my local shared directory (SHARED_PATH)

Now this LOCAL_REPO is used amon a set of people and any changes that they commit will be to LOCAL_REPO which can be synced with MASTER.
So i tried creating local branch(MY_LOCAL) for myself at some path.

1. git clone SHARED_PATH
2. got checkout -b MY_LOCAL LOCAL_REPO

I am facing following issues :

1. when i create MY_LOCAL MASTER is checked out by default. Should it not be LOCAL_REPO
2. while trying the second option i get the following error :

> Blockquote
>   fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches

After that i tried "git remote show origin" , this shows me LOCAL_REPO as remote and tracked.
What is the mistake i am doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're doing a `git clone` it will checkout a `master` branch by default. To specify branch during clone use (in your case)

```
git clone SHARED_PATH -b LOCAL_REPO
```

And for your 2nd issue, probably `git pull --all` should help